# How to add a new column to SSIS destination

Tags: ssis

I just added a new field to my OLE DB Source in an SSIS package. It then goes to a Flat file Destination. In the Flat file destination object, the field shows up under available inpt columns but doesnt show up anywhere else (Available destination Columns, or the bottom box that lists fields)

How do i get this as an available destination field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into the Flat File Connection manager used by your destination object, go to Advanced, and click "New", then add the column properties.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the destination and recreate it, it usually works.

Comment: I also do this.  It's best to get clean metadata and will usually save time in the end.